# Allow users background music in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift2

I am looking for some code to allow the user to play music from their phone while still using my app. Previously before swift 2.0 i would put this in the app delegate and it would work perfectly:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

Does anyone know how to implement this in swift 2.0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following would be the syntax for Swift 2 calling `setCategory` and `setActive` on `AVSession`:

```
do
{
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
}
```

**OR**

```
do
{
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! I'm still getting used to the new swift syntax

Comment: Does it work with audio executed from a WKWebView? It seems to ignore the silent switch and plays sound even when the device is muted. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/105912

Comment: Thank you!! What did programmers do in prehistoric times before SO existed? ;-)