# Playing Audio With Swift 2 in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play background music on an app I am creating, but none of the solutions I have seen online work. I have experimented with about 5 different blocks of code that others said worked for them but have been short of success on all the attempts. My current code is down below(it is also not working even though there are no errors), I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could give me an explanation as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
func playBackgroundMusic() {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cool_song", ofType: "mp3")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32674088/4475605

Comment: are u getting the correct path?

Comment: Yes that is the correct URL path